# Convert array of strings in arrays of integers in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to convert an array of strings in arrays of integers associating its ids in a dataframe column.

That's because I need to map a list of home rooms per id like the next shows:

That's the JSON I have to map:

```
[ 
   {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "dining room",
   }, 
   {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "living room",
   },
   {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "guest room",
   },
   {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "bathroom",
   },
   {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "game room",
   },
   {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "kitchen",
   },
   {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "storage room",
   },
   {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "bedroom",
   },
   {
      "id": 9,
      "name": "family room",
   }
]
```

That's the dataframe I have:

```py
index     home_rooms             
0         [dining room, living room, bathroom]                     
1         [guest room, kitchen, game room] 
2         [storage room, family room, bedroom] 
3         [dining room, living room, bathroom] 
4         [guest room, kitchen, game room]
5         [storage room, family room, bedroom] 
6         [dining room, living room, bathroom] 
7         [guest room, kitchen, game room]
8         [storage room, family room, bedroom]
```

And that's the dataframe I need:

```py
index     home_rooms             
0         [1, 2, 4]                     
1         [3, 6, 5] 
2         [7, 9, 8] 
3         [1, 2, 4]
4         [3, 6, 5]
5         [7, 9, 8] 
6         [1, 2, 4] 
7         [3, 6, 5]
8         [7, 9, 8]
```

Any solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really want a column with lists? You are losing all the speed and ease of pandas.

Comment: Yes, I need a column with lists, because the idea is generate a dict with other columns. Later, I'll post a JSON to API which attribute of home_rooms must be an array of integers.

Comment: You should do that conversion as late as possible, but your decision.

Comment: I guess the column `home_room` in your dataframe contains the typo in the spelling of `dining`, right?

Comment: Right, @ShubhamSharma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
mapper = pd.read_json(jsonstr).set_index('name')['id']
df_out = df.explode('home_rooms').replace('dinig room', 'dining room') #fix typo with replace
df_out['home_rooms'] = df_out['home_rooms'].map(mapper)
df_out.groupby('index').agg(list).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   index home_rooms
0      0  [1, 2, 4]
1      1  [3, 6, 5]
2      2  [7, 9, 8]
3      3  [1, 2, 4]
4      4  [3, 6, 5]
5      5  [7, 9, 8]
6      6  [1, 2, 4]
7      7  [3, 6, 5]
8      8  [7, 9, 8]
```

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Thanks.

Comment: I get this error: "Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects".

Comment: @StivenRamírezArango Do you have duplicate names in your json string?

Comment: Yes, but with different id.

Comment: Okay, that is a problem, which id do you use if 'house' can have an id of 1 and id of 5? You have ambiguity about which to use.

Comment: I'd use the first.

Comment: But in this case I'll remove duplicates before mapper

Comment: `mapper = pd.read_json(jsonstr).drop_duplicates('name').set_index('name')['id']`

Comment: Ok, I obtained  NaN in the column, but maybe it's because string was not mapped exactly. Is there a way to map if string contains at least a word of json dict?

Comment: Okay, you are extending this question, best to close this question and start a new question.

Comment: I agree OP should close this question and revise it with more detail. It seems his `home_rooms` also has single value of float.

Comment: Well, I'll start a new question. Thanks. This question was resolved successfully.

Answer (score 3):

Let's call the json string as `l_str`. Load it to dataframe as `df_map`. From `df_map` construct dictionary `d` in the structure `name: id`. Use `itemgetter` and list comprehension to construct list of `id` per `index`

```
from operator import itemgetter

df_map = pd.read_json(l_str)
d = dict(zip(df_map.name, df_map.id))
df['home_rooms'] = [list(itemgetter(*x)(d)) for x in df.home_rooms]

Out[415]:
   index home_rooms
0      0  [1, 2, 4]
1      1  [3, 6, 5]
2      2  [7, 9, 8]
3      3  [1, 2, 4]
4      4  [3, 6, 5]
5      5  [7, 9, 8]
6      6  [1, 2, 4]
7      7  [3, 6, 5]
8      8  [7, 9, 8]
```

Comment: I get this error: "type object argument after * must be an iterable, not float".

Comment: It means your columns `df.home_rooms` besides having `list` also having `float`. As Scott commented, you should revised or post new question with more detail representing your data

Comment: Yes, I'll use a representative data because the example was short.